# Magento not updating record through model

Tags: magento, model-view-controller

Has anyone got a clue why this code does not update the column order_id in my database?
Is it because we are in model-context? Because similar code does work in controller-context.

If I dump the $order variable, I can see that it has updated the order_id value of the object, but this is not saved into the database.

These are the fields in the table planner_orders:

```
id  int
order_id    bigint
visitor_id  bigint
store_id    int
repair_customers_id int
start_timeslot  timestamp
timeslots   int
location    varchar
vat double
total_vat   double
created timestamp
```

.

```
<?php
class Alphabase_Planner_Model_Order extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('planner/order');
    }

    public function create($visitor, $store, $customer, $start, $timeslots = 0, $location, $vat, $total_vat) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('planner/order')
            ->setData('visitor_id', $visitor)
            ->setData('store_id', $store)
            ->setData('repair_customers_id', $customer)
            ->setData('start_timeslot', $start)
            ->setData('timeslots', $timeslots)
            ->setData('location', $location)
            ->setData('vat', $vat)
            ->setData('total_vat', $total_vat)
            ->setData('created', now())
            ->save();
        $id = $order->id;
        $order_id = $store.sprintf('%08d', $id);
        $order->setOrderId($order_id);
        $order->save();
        return $order;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tested same code and it works. Nothing wrong with code. Have you checked that cache is not troubling you? If you set order_id in first call(for testing hardcode order_id value) and then save, is it saving data or same issue is coming?

Comment: What is $store? Why $order->id should work?
Please, show var_dump($store) and var_dump(sprintf('%08d', $id)), add it before $order->setOrderId($order_id);

Comment: $store is the store_id, which is (int) 8 in the example.

Comment: Crazy thing, but I let the thing rest for the night and now it works! Thanks anyway for your thoughts.